# Employee/History - Part of composite key as foreign key

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, constraints, entities, composite-primary-key

I've got 2 entities:

1) EMPLOYEES (Parent)

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
employee_id       NUMBER   (3)    NOT NULL,
first_name        VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
last_name         VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
job_title         VARCHAR (20)    NOT NULL,
employee_type     VARCHAR  (1)    NOT NULL,
salary            NUMBER   (5),
hourly_pay        NUMBER (5,2),
bonus_pay         NUMBER (5,2),

CONSTRAINT employee_pk PRIMARY KEY(employee_id));
```

2) EMPLOYEE_HISTORY (Child)

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_HISTORY (
start_date        DATE            NOT NULL,
employee_id       NUMBER   (3)    NOT NULL,
end_date          DATE,
job_title         VARCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
hourly_rate       NUMBER (5,2)    NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT employee_history_pk PRIMARY KEY(start_date, employee_id));
```

I'm trying to create:

```
ALTER TABLE employee_history
  ADD CONSTRAINT employee_history_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
      REFERENCES employee_history(employee_id);
```

When I do this, I get an error

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

My guess is that I cannot create the constraint on just `employee_id` because I have a composite key in my child table. I understand when an employee gets put into the database, the parent table is filled out and the "start date" should be filled out along with everything else. However, I do not understand how this would work if I had start_date in my parent table as well. I would be able to create my constraint, yes, but how will I be able to keep a record of changes in start_date if my start_date was inputted at the time of when the employee was entered into the database.
I thought about using job_title as a primary key instead of start_date because it's present in both tables, but what happens when an employee gets promoted and demoted again? Won't a duplicate value constraint come up when the same employee_id and job_title is getting inserted?

Comment: I don't follow-- why can't you create the foreign key on `employee_id`?  The fact that the child table has a composite primary key has no impact on your ability to define a foreign key constraint using just one of the two columns.  Does your `ALTER TABLE` statement throw an exception?  If so, what exception?

Comment: Apologies, the error I get is: "ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `references` clause needs to reference the parent table.  Not the child table

```
ALTER TABLE employee_history
  ADD CONSTRAINT employee_history_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_id)
      REFERENCES employee(employee_id); -- employee not employee_history
```

The SQL you posted is trying to create a self-referential foreign key where `employee_history` is both the parent and the child.  That doesn't make sense in this case.

Comment: What an oversight! I feel embarrassed.. Thank you so much Justin, I really appreciate your helpful and quick responses!